# Cannot access dockerized wordpress via custom domain using nginx reverse proxy (full setup details inside)

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, ubuntu, nginx

I have an Ubuntu server 20.04
I have nginx installed on that server (nginx is not dockerized)
There are many docker apps running which nginx is proxying for fine.
I am trying to run Wordpress in a docker container using the official Wordpress image and point my domain to nginx which uses proxy_pass to point it to Wordpress container.
When I spin up my docker container, I can access it fine via the IP address but when I try to access it via my domain, I get a redirect loop.

Here is my setup:

DNS Records

```
A - @ - X.X.X.X
A - www - X.X.X.X
```

nginx config

```
server {
    server_name domain.io www.domain.io;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234;
    }
}
server {
    if ($host = mydomain.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = www.mydomain.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.io www.mydomain.io;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 1234:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST:
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD:
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME:
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE:
      MYSQL_USER:
      MYSQL_PASSWORD:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD:
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  wordpress:
  db:
```

The error I'm getting
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEtHh.jpg